# How to combine first name and last name in powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hello everyone I am currently learning PowerShell, and I have script were I can create a Active Directory User, And I am trying to combine the first name and last name (firstname.lastname) and set it where it says $logonname so the user will not have to input that information. Is there some type of command used to achieve that ?

```
    import-module activedirectory

#Define variable
$OU ="OU=mine,DC=mine,DC=mine"



$firstname = Read-Host 'Enter New Users First Name'


$lastname = Read-Host 'Enter New Users Last Name'

$logonname = Read-Host 'Enter New Users Windows Logon Name'

$EmailAddress = "$logonname@mine.com"

$Description = Read-Host 'Job Title?'

$Landline = Read-Host 'Enter the Users Landline Phone (if applicable)'

$Mobile = Read-Host 'Mobile Phone? (If Applicable)'

$Password = Read-Host 'Please enter a secure password'





New-ADUser -Name "$firstname $lastname" -EmailAddress $EmailAddress -DisplayName "$firstname $lastname" -SamAccountName $logonname -Title $Description -UserPrincipalName "$logonname@mine.com" -GivenName $firstname -Surname $lastname -Description $Description -OfficePhone $Landline -MobilePhone $Mobile



Write-Host 'Setting Account Details...'



Write-Host 'Setting Password...'

Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $logonname -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "$Password" -Force)

Set-ADUser -Identity $logonname -PasswordNeverExpires $true



Write-Host 'Setting Home Directory to \\networklocation\Home'

Set-ADUser -Identity $logonname -HomeDirectory \\networklocation\home -HomeDrive H



Write-Host 'Enabling Account in Active Directory..

**NOTE**

The Account Will Take 30 Seconds To Enable, It Is Safe To Close The Script As Long as you See the "DONE" Prompt.'

Enable-ADAccount -Identity $logonname



Write-Host 'Done'
```

Comment: $logonname = $firstname + $lastname

Comment: Thank you Doug. How do I add a period in between ? I want to have it like ex.(david.banner).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your script so that `$logonname` is using the values from `$firstname` and `$lastname` then you can do that in a couple different ways.

I also see in the comments that you want a `.` in between.

This is how I would do it:

```
$logonname = "$firstname.$lastname";
```

---

As a side note, I personally don't have experience with AD, however, allowing the user to type in whatever they want, and then using that info could lead to problems.

What if the user types symbols that are not allowed in a username or in an email address?

If you are the only one using this script and you're just writing it to make your job easier, then that's probably fine. But I would be wary of allowing others to run it.

What happens if any one of these commands which depend on the previous command, fails?

I realize you said you're learning. So this is a good opportunity to learn about error handling, checking your inputs and verifying they are valid, etc.

Comment: Thank you Chad, when I said users I meant just me lol.

Comment: @DehavenBrown cool. If you feel that my post answered your question, be sure to mark it as the answer.

Comment: this answered my question. Thank you !